# How to align subcaption of image with different size?

Tags: floats, subfloats

I need to align the caption of images above.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx,psfrag,epsf}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{verbatim}

%\usepackage[subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\newcommand{\bs}{\boldsymbol}
%\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alph{subfigure}}

% correct bad hyphenation here

%\pdfminorversion=4
% NOTE: To produce blinded version, replace "0" with "1" below.
\newcommand{\blind}{0}

% DON'T change margins - should be 1 inch all around.
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}%
\addtolength{\textheight}{-.3in}%
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.8in}%

\begin{document}

The Figure~\ref{descriptive1} is composed by Figure~\ref{fig:hist_longair} and Figure~\ref{fig:curve_longair}.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{tom.png}
        \caption{Tom is a cat}
        \label{fig:hist_longair}        
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.75\linewidth]{jerry.png}
        \caption{Jerry is a mouse}
        \label{fig:curve_longair}       
    \end{subfigure} 
    \caption{Tom and Jerry are animals}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

My figures are:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why don't you set the same `height` rather than `width`?

Comment: If the captions fit on one line, use \begin{subfigure}[b]...

Comment: I need to keep up the proportions.

Comment: Use `height` ***rather than*** `width` was the suggestion.